# ByRef argument type mismatch - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Afternoon,

I have a function to calculate week day name from a date:

```
Function calcWeekdayName(calcDate As Date) As String

Dim calcWeekday As Integer
calcWeekday = Weekday(calcDate, vbMonday)

calcWeekdayName = weekdayName(calcWeekday, True, vbMonday)

End Function
```

I am then using a Public variable to pass the date to this function. The Public variable is declared on Sheet 2:

```
Public searchDate As Date
```

The variable is then set in the sub below my function:

```
searchDate = Worksheets("Update Data").Range("B3").Value
```

B3 on Update Data is formatted dd/mm/yyyy

When I try to set the variable weekdayName using the function and the searchDate variable I get a ByRef argument type mismatch.

On Sheet 2:

```
 Public weekdayName As String
```

In Sub:

```
 weekdayName = calcWeekdayName(searchDate)
```

The current value of B3 is 28/03/2016 but I have also tried 01/01/2016.

Cheers

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of all your code modules.

Comment: When I'm using public variables? So I need to ReDim them all in each module?

Comment: @megatron77 - In answer to your question, no.  I will help determine if you have a scope issue though.  What exactly do you mean by "The variable is then set in the *sub below my function*". I'm guessing that whatever the compiler is passing as `searchDate` isn't a Date when you make the call.

Comment: As your variables are in object modules (as opposed to just modules), you need to access them by full name that includes the object name, such as `Sheet2.searchDate`. Using `Option Explicit` helps you identify errors of this type, because apparently at the point where you use `searchDate` it is an undeclared variable of type `Variant`. And after having fixed that (and only after that), you should really change you function's signature to `ByVal calcDate As Date`.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks using the object name worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sheet2` is a worksheet object - the code-behind for it is a *class module*.

Class modules and "standard modules" are different in that their `Public` members require an *instance* to be accessible.

So you can do `Sheet2.MyPublicVariable = 42`, but you can't do just `MyPublicVariable = 42` *unless you're in the same module that's declaring that variable*.

Your problem would have been prevented by specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of the module; then, `searchDate` would have been unaccessible and thus undeclared, and the VBA code would have refused to compile.

By *not* specifying `Option Explicit`, you allowed the use of *undeclared variables*, and that is the root of all evil in VBA.

Use. Option. Explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with WeekDayName variable. You should rename it myWeekDayName to avoid confusion with the VBA function of the same name.

```
Public searchDate As Date
Public myWeekDayName As String

Function calcWeekdayName(calcDate As Date) As String
    Dim calcWeekday As Integer
    calcWeekday = Weekday(calcDate, vbMonday)
    calcWeekdayName = VBA.weekdayName(calcWeekday, True, vbMonday)
End Function

Sub test()
    searchDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
    myWeekDayName = calcWeekdayName(searchDate)
End Sub
```